# Javascript strings with %s variables

Tags: javascript, string

I'm looking Javascript's equivalent for this piece of code:

```
var ERROR = "Received error: %s";

function reportError (err) {
    reporter.log(ERROR, err);
}
```

Is there such built-in functionality in Javascript? like in C#, Java and so..?

Comment: no, there may be a library to do it

Comment: `console.log()` can use [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions). In your example, if you replace `reporter` by `console`, it will work.

Comment: @JaromandaX - No library needed. See link to duplicate.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - you're right, 4 years ago I didn't know console.log could do that :p